# Ubuntu run script as non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sudo, su

I've an init script (/etc/init.d) that should run a my executable jar file as a serviceat boot. I need that this script is runned by a specified user.

With su & sudo is possibile but it split the process and I don't like this.

There is another way to run this script as limited user?

This is the relevant part of my init script:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_NAME="myapp"
APP_HOME=/home/user1/jetty
JAVA_HOME=/opt/local/java/latest
echo "Service $APP_NAME - [$1]"

echo "JAVA_HOME -> $JAVA_HOME"
echo "APP_HOME -> $APP_HOME"
echo "APP_NAME -> $APP_NAME"

function start {
    if pkill -0 -f $APP_NAME.jar > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        echo "Service [$APP_NAME] is already running. Ignoring startup request."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Starting application..."
    cd $APP_HOME
    nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar $APP_HOME/$APP_NAME.jar\
        < /dev/null > $APP_HOME/logs/app.log 2>&1 &
}
```

Comment: Please post Ubuntu specific questions to http://askubuntu.com or more general Unix/Linux questions to unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you should use the program `start-stop-daemon` for this. It has options for launching daemons as different users, managing pid files, changing the working directory, and pretty much anything else that is usually needed by init scripts.